# Why does my python function not return my value although i am using return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, return-value

So I wanted to make a game to learn the capitals of each state in Germany.
First it asks you how many questions you want to get using variable v. Then each round c is supposed to show weather you answered right or not with each time answering correctly adding 1 point to b, your final score which will be printed. However the pull_card() function doesn't seem to be returning c and I don't understand why.

```
import random

def pull_card():
    """
    Picks a random state from germany.
    Works as intended, may be ignored.
    """
    random.seed()
    x=random.randint(0,16)
    if x==0:
        land='Baden-Württemberg'
    elif x==1:
        land='Bayern'
    elif x==2:
        land='Berlin'
    elif x==3:
        land='Brandenburg'
    elif x==4:
        land='Bremen'
    elif x==5:
        land='Hamburg'
    elif x==6:
        land='Hessen'
    elif x==7:
        land='Mecklenburg-Vorpommern'
    elif x==8:
        land='Niedersachsen'
    elif x==9:
        land='Nordrhein-Westfalen'
    elif x==10:
        land='Rheinland-Pfalz'
    elif x==11:
        land='Saarland'
    elif x==12:
        land='Sachsen'
    elif x==13:
        land='Sachsen-Anhalt'
    elif x==14:
        land='Schleswig-Holstein'
    else:
        land='Thüringen'
    """
    Asks you for the city of the state in the form of an input string.
    Checks if the given city and state match.
    Doesn't work as intended:
    c won't be returned!
    """
    y=str(input("What is the capital of " + land + "?"))
    if x==0 and y=="Stuttgart":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==1 and y=="München":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==2 and y=="Berlin":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==3 and y=="Potsdam":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==4 and y=="Bremen":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==5 and y=="Hamburg":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==6 and y=="Wiesbaden":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==7 and y=="Schwerin":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==8 and y=="Hannover":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==9 and y=="Düsseldorf":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==10 and y=="Mainz":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==11 and y=="Saarbrücken":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==12 and y=="Dresden":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==13 and y=="Magdeburg":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==14 and y=="Kiel":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==15 and y=="Erfurt":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
        c=0
        return c
"""
Asks how often you wanna play and executes the function where the game is.
Accumulates your correct answers and prints out how much you've got right.
"""
b=0
v=int(input("How many times do you wanna play?"))
while 0!=v:
    v=v-1
    pull_card()
    if c==1:
        b=b+1
    else:
        pass
else:
    pass
print("You've had " + b + " correct!")
```

Here's the error message:

```
How many times do you wanna play?2
What is the capital of Sachsen?Dresden
Correct!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hauptstaedte.py", line 126, in <module>
    if c==1:
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

I feel like I am using return wrong but I don't get how.
Thank you for taking your time and helping me.

Comment: The `return` statement returns the value, not the variable. You have to assign the return value to a variable. Use `c=pull_card()`.

Comment: You should consider looking into `random.choice` and using a list of tuples to contain all of your state/capital pairs.  Would reduce your code by like 90%

Comment: Hi Craig, I didn't quite understand the other post you linked, but your explanation did it for me. I posted an answer to my question, where the improved code is, but will try to further improve it, using random.choice. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to craig, I realized what my mistake was.
Return only returns values and not variables!
I made some adjustments and it now works as intended.
I will also look into Chris's suggestion to put random.choice() into my code to make it shorter.
Thank you craig!

```
import random

def pull_card():
    """
    Picks a random state from germany.
    Works as intended, may be ignored.
    """
    random.seed()
    x=random.randint(0,16)
    if x==0:
        land='Baden-Württemberg'
    elif x==1:
        land='Bayern'
    elif x==2:
        land='Berlin'
    elif x==3:
        land='Brandenburg'
    elif x==4:
        land='Bremen'
    elif x==5:
        land='Hamburg'
    elif x==6:
        land='Hessen'
    elif x==7:
        land='Mecklenburg-Vorpommern'
    elif x==8:
        land='Niedersachsen'
    elif x==9:
        land='Nordrhein-Westfalen'
    elif x==10:
        land='Rheinland-Pfalz'
    elif x==11:
        land='Saarland'
    elif x==12:
        land='Sachsen'
    elif x==13:
        land='Sachsen-Anhalt'
    elif x==14:
        land='Schleswig-Holstein'
    else:
        land='Thüringen'
    """
    Asks you for the city of the state in the form of an input string.
    Checks if the given city and state match.
    Doesn't work as intended:
    c won't be returned!
    """
    y=str(input("What is the capital of " + land + "?"))
    if x==0 and y=="Stuttgart":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==1 and y=="München":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==2 and y=="Berlin":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==3 and y=="Potsdam":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==4 and y=="Bremen":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==5 and y=="Hamburg":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==6 and y=="Wiesbaden":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==7 and y=="Schwerin":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==8 and y=="Hannover":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==9 and y=="Düsseldorf":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==10 and y=="Mainz":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==11 and y=="Saarbrücken":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==12 and y=="Dresden":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==13 and y=="Magdeburg":
        print("Correct!")
        c=1
        return c
    elif x==14 and y=="Kiel":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    elif x==15 and y=="Erfurt":
        print("Correct!")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
        return 0
"""
Asks how often you wanna play and executes the function where the game is.
Accumulates your correct answers and prints out how much you've got right.
"""
b=0
v=int(input("How many times do you wanna play?"))
while 0!=v:
    v=v-1
    c=pull_card()
    if c==1:
        b=b+1
    else:
        pass
else:
    pass
print("You've had " + str(b) + " correct!")
```

Comment: It wasn't [Craig's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7517724/craig) suggestion to use `random.choice`, it was [Chris's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718350/chris).

Comment: Oh your right, it was Chris's. Thanks, I'll change that right away.